# A missing link in the food chain

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, visual

[image: food_chain_of_fish]

Text only:

```
SHED  HEAT  VIES  WING  RING  END  SUE  ?  ROTE  SET  ORB
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The missing link is the word:

> **PIN**

Why? Because if we consider this 'food chain'...

> In every pair of adjacent 'fish' (i.e. words) the fish/word on the left can *eat* the fish/word to its immediate right in order to form a longer word. Here, 'eating' implies placing the right-hand word whole between two of the letters of the left-hand word.
>
>  So, for example, when SET eats ORB on the right-hand end, we get S(ORB)ET. And when SHED eats HEAT on the left-hand end, we get S(HEAT)HED.

We therefore need to add the word...

> **PIN**, in order to get **SU(PIN)E** when SUE eats PIN, and **P(ROTE)IN** when PIN eats ROTE.

The fully resolved food chain thus works out as:

> S(HEAT)HED-HEA(VIES)T-VIE(WING)S-W(RING)ING-R(END)ING-EN(SUE)D-**SU(PIN)E-P(ROTE)IN**-RO(SET)TE-S(ORB)ET